# Parameters from jQuery.load() not passed to Controller Action method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC3 View I have a textbox linked to a Model property, like so:

```
 <tr> 
        <td>Name contains:</td> 
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NameContains, new { @style = "width:99%" })</td> 
        <td>@Html.ImageButton("Search", "nameContainsSearchButton")</td> 
</tr>
```

My Image button is used in a piece of script to call the appropriate method on the controller that returns a partial view, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#nameContainsSearchButton').click(function () {

        var data = $("#NameContains").val();

        // send an AJAX request to the controller action
        $('#searchResults').load("/QuickSearch/Search", data);

        return false;
    });
});
```

As you can see, I am trying to pass the value of the TextBox 'NameContains' as a parameter to my controller method. However, the parameter received by the method is always null.

Anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Lucien.

**EDIT: I got the above working by changing the call to:**

```
$('#searchResults').load("/QuickSearch/Search", {nameContains: data});
```

where `nameContains` is the name of the parameter in the action method.

I have a follow-up question, though: how can I pass the entire Model as a parameter to an action method? There's another page where the user can enter many search criteria and I want to just pass the entire search criteria model object to the controller....

Comment: what does the rendered HTML look like?

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it wrong,
take a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/, you passed data as callback which should be invoked after server response,
it should be

```
$('#searchResults').load("/QuickSearch/",{Search: data});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I figured that one out just before I read your answer. However, it does not look like I require the method name as a parameter in my case (the method will return a partial view). Any ideas about my follow-up question (see edit)?

Answer (score 1):

You could send your entire model as a JSON request:

```
var model = {
    nameContains: $('#NameContains').val(),
    someOtherPropertyName: 'some other value',
    someComplexObject: {
        complexProp1: 'value 1',
        complexCollectionProp: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    }
};

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Search", "QuickSearch")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    success: function(result) {
        $('#searchResults').html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: That looks promising. I guess I don't need your first code snippet as the (Razor) code in the rest of my page already updates the model. What would the signature of my controller method look like in this case - specifically the type of the parameter? And would I still return a PartialView?

Comment: @LucienDol, in this case the action will take a single parameter which will represent your view model. It will have the same properties as the javascript object defined below: `nameContains`, `someOtherPropertyName`, `someComplexObject` (with `complexProp1` and `complexCollectionProp`). As far as the return type is concerned that would entire depend on what you are trying to achieve. Could be a partial view, yet another JSON object, XML, etc ...

Comment: So this does not have to be a JSON parameter type (if such a thing exists)?

Comment: @LucienDol, no, a plain POCO object.

Comment: @LucienDol, you subscribe to the .click event handler of the button: `$('#id_of_your_button').click(function() { ... });`

Comment: Dimitriv - I still can't get this to work. I have copied your .ajax code and inserted it into my .click method as you recommended. But how do I correctly create a variable that contains a serialized version of my model? My .cshtml starts with  the razor code "@model bla.bla.UserSearch" and I can use the model fine in the rest of the page, but when I try to refer to it in javascript it does not recognize it. I have tried "var data = @model", "var data = @Model" and various other forms, but it either gives an error message or it says it's undefined. How do I write this??

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter 'data' should have key-value format, f.ex:

```
$("#objectID").load("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] } );
```

Not just value. See third example in documentation http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Yes, you are right. I figured that one out just before I read your answer. Any ideas about my follow-up question (see edit)?